# Gradle cannot find plugin

Tags: grails, gradle, spring-security, build.gradle, grails-plugin

I have the following in my build.gradle of my Grails 3 project.

```
dependencies {
...
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3"
    // The following line was the true cause of my problem
    compile("org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth-google:0.3.1")
...
}
```

Now when I run Gradle I get this error:

```
Error Error initializing classpath: Could not find spring-security-core.zip (org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3).
Searched in the following locations:
https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.0.3/spring-security-core-3.0.3.zip (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

If I go to the specified [path](https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.0.3/) I do see the plugin but just as reported there is no zip file.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Something is very broken if it's looking for a plugin zip in Grails 3. I keep a simple demo app for the plugin at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tree/master/secured - see if there's anything helpful there.

Comment: Can you also show your repositories section and if you have it buildscript section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root for this problem I found in a little bit different place than expected.
I am working on upgrading a Grails 2.5 project to Grails 3 and I had lead myself on a wrong track. I needed to include `spring-security-oauth-google` and when it did not work as expected I also included `spring-security-core` which then derailed me.
The cause of this problem is dependencies being loaded from dependencies I have in my own project. In order to avoid loading those dependencies - called transitive dependencies - the following has to be done:

```
plugins {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3"
    compile("org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth-google:0.3.1") {
        exclude group: 'org.grails.plugins', module: 'spring-security-core'
    }
}
```

This will load the `spring-security-core 3.0.3` correctly ignoring the dependency from `spring-security-oauth-google`.